# What's the equivalent of a SQL IN statement in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite new to AngularJS, and I'm trying to figure out how to apply a filter where a record id is one of a list of ids in an array.  in SQL, it would be something like:

```
SELECT * from Table1 where Table1.ID in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

How would I accomplish the same thing in AngularJS?  I know I need to apply filtering, but how?

Comment: Are you interested in AngularJS Filters or just the JavaScript equivalent to SQL IN? If the second one, you are looking for `indexOf`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: A little of both, actually.  The code I'm maintaining has created a custom filtering solution and I was trying to figure out how to add to it a filter based upon items chosen in a multi-select.  It does look like indexOf is the way to go, as I'm not seeing anything that specifically does what I want it to do in Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using pure Javascript using a combination of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/some).

Example:

```
let a = [{id: 1, val: 'aaa'},
         {id: 2, val: 'bbb'},
         {id: 3, val: 'ccc'},
         {id: 4, val: 'ddd'},
         {id: 5, val: 'eee'},
         {id: 6, val: 'fff'},
         {id: 7, val: 'ggg'},
         {id: 8, val: 'hhh'}];

let b = [1,2,5,6];

let result = a.filter(x => b.some(y => y === x.id));
```

Result (stringified):

```
[{"id":1,"val":"aaa"},{"id":2,"val":"bbb"},{"id":5,"val":"eee"},{"id":6,"val":"fff"}]
```

In ES5 you'd write:

```
var result = a.filter(function(x) { return b.some(function(y) { return y === x.id; }); });
```

Comment: This may work - question though, is this the preferred way of writing this, or is it just a different way of doing what Marcus H. did and both are correct?

Comment: If you want to filter by id, Marcus' answer will only work on an array of int, not on an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a controller/service method which will filter out certain records from an array you 
could use plain javascript for that. Here I'm using the filter() method which array implements, more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var inStatementData = [3,6,7];

function isInArray(value, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}

var resultArray= data.filter(function(value){
    return isInArray(value, inStatementData);
});

 //resultArray will be [3,6,7]
```

Comment: I think this may work.  It's not what I was hoping for, but it's the one I can definitely use..  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using [ng-repeat with filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

SQL Object in JS:

```
$scope.results = [
   { id: 1, name: 'tom', job: 'doctor' },
   { id: 2, name: 'bob', job: 'dentist' },
   { id: 3, name: 'steve', job: 'teacher' }
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results | filter: { id: 1} | filter: { id: 2}">
<span>{{result.name}}</span>
<span>{{result.job}}</span>
</div>
```

You can also make it cleaner with an angular function:

JS:

```
$scope.idFilter = function (result) { 
var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
if($.inArray(result, myArray) !== -1){
      return result;
   }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results | filter: idFilter">
```

Comment: This would work; however, the list of items I'm checking against is many - 40+.  Do I really need to do an if statement 40+ times?

Comment: I have updated my answer using jquery's [inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).